# What exactly is $p(x,y)$ in the context of iid assumption in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, random-variable, definition, iid

In machine learning iid assumption means that examples in the dataset are independent and drawn from the same probability distribution (i.e., identically distributed).

Here, the probability distribution is denoted by $p(x,y)$ where $x$ is vector and $y$ is a scalar. I have a confusing understanding $p(x,y)$. Are both $x$ and $y$ random variables? When people say iid, are they referring to $x$ or $y$ or both? Or do we have here a single random variable?

Comment: **$x$** is a realisation of a random vector **$X$** (i.e. multivariate random variable) with (say) $k$ components $x_1,...,x_k$ and $y$ is a random variable $Y$(i.e. a random vector of size $1$). $(x,y)=(x_1,...,x_k,y)$ is a random vector with $k+1$ components, the first $k$ of which form a realisation of **$X$**. This Wikipedia article will help you become acquainted with random vectors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable.

Comment: @MickyboYakari Can we say both X and Y iid?

Comment: No because being i.i.d. is a property that applies to samples. One would have to say that $(\boldsymbol{X_1},Y_1),(\boldsymbol{X_2},Y_2),...,(\boldsymbol{X_n},Y_n)$ are i.i.d., where $n$ is the sample size and each index pertains to one observation in the sample. We basically sampled $n$ réalisations of the random vector $(\boldsymbol{X},Y)$ independently.